# Handling column names with spaces in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have created a SQL Query to update various columns, where the column names contain spaces. It works if I run it manually as a query:

```
UPDATE dbo.Survey
SET PhotoPathQ1='(null)'
WHERE "Q1 Photo Taken"='0'

UPDATE dbo.Survey
SET PhotoPathQ2='(null)'
WHERE "Q2 Photo Taken"='0'

UPDATE dbo.Survey
SET PhotoPathQ3='(null)'
WHERE "Q3 Photo Taken"='0'

... and further similar updates
```

However if I try to automate this using SQL Server Agent as a Transact-SQL script (T-SQL) it does not actually do anything to my table, the job says that it has run successfully but the data has not been updated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Am I missing something obvious with this?

Comment: make sure the database context is set correctly for the job that runs. more than likely it is running against the wrong db.

Comment: thanks for the response. I checked the database that is selected in the job and it is the correct one

Comment: try replacing the quotes around the column names with square brackets such as [Q1 Photo Taken]

Comment: What's the job output? Should at least be 8 'rows affected' messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like an error in your syntax, try this as an example:

```
UPDATE dbo.Survey
SET PhotoPathQ1 = null
WHERE [Q1 Photo Taken] = 0
```

This assumes that the field `PhotoPathQ1` is `nullable` and you actually want to insert a true `null` value in to it rather than a string `'(null)'`.

It also assumes that `[Q1 Photo Taken]` is a `bit` or `int` field, although SQL Server will handle the conversion happily if you have it in quotes. If it's a string data type, then you should leave the quotes there.

You should use square brackets on field names that contain spaces instead of double quotes:

`[Q1 Photo Taken]`

Comment: Thanks everyone speech marks were my issue and putting the square brackets fixed it.

Comment: @user3820933 if `PhotoPathQ1` is nullable, you may still want to insert a proper `null` value in to it rather than a string, as handling a true `null` value is better than comparing strings.

Comment: thank you I have also amended the null values so that my script is now:
        UPDATE dbo.Survey
        SET PhotoPathQ1 = null
        WHERE [Q1 Photo Taken] = '0'

Comment: @user3820933 no problem, it will save you work in the long run.